# Make XML in c# with namespaces

Tags: c#, xml, xml-namespaces, xmldocument

I need to generate XML in the following form:

```
<ns1:root xmlns:ns1="http://example.com/xmlns1" xmlns:ns2="http://example.com/xmlns2">
    <ns2:item ns2:param="value" />
</ns1:root>
```

I use this code:

```
XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
XmlElement xRootElement = (XmlElement)xDoc.AppendChild(xDoc.CreateElement("ns1:root"));
xRootElement.SetAttribute("xmlns:ns1", "http://example.com/xmlns1");
xRootElement.SetAttribute("xmlns:ns2", "http://example.com/xmlns2");
XmlElement xElement = (XmlElement)xRootElement.AppendChild(xDoc.CreateElement("ns2:item"));
xElement.SetAttribute("ns2:param", "value");
```

But the result is the following:

```
<root xmlns:ns1="http://example.com/xmlns1" xmlns:ns2="http://example.com/xmlns2">
    <item param="value" />
</root>
```

Thanks for the advice.

Comment: [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387075.aspx) is examples how to create xmls with namespace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XmlElement xElement = (XmlElement)xRootElement.AppendChild(xDoc.CreateElement("ns2:item"**, "http://example.com/xmlns2"));**

Gave me:

```
<root xmlns:ns1="http://example.com/xmlns1" xmlns:ns2="http://example.com/xmlns2">
  <ns2:item param="value" />
</root>
```

By the way, `"ns2:param"` is not necessary. XML attributes belong to the same namespace as the element.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
XmlElement xRootElement = (XmlElement)xDoc.AppendChild(xDoc.CreateElement("ns1:root"));
xRootElement.SetAttribute("xmlns:ns1", "http://example.com/xmlns1");
xRootElement.SetAttribute("xmlns:ns2", "http://example.com/xmlns2");
XmlElement xElement =     (XmlElement)xRootElement.AppendChild(xDoc.CreateElement("item", "http://example.com/xmlns1"));
xElement.SetAttribute("param", "http://example.com/xmlns1", "value");
```